# Python start function as thread won't join/end

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I am currently having issues with a thread joining. I have a function that does a set list of operations depending on the parameters given. There is a "start" button that will start the function and this function gets run as a thread.

The same button turns into a "stop" button that will stop the function when clicked. Unfortunately, thread does not seem to end.

The relevant code is here... Note that "self.stop_com_loop" Is used to end the thread...

Any comments would be great.

```
def Start_Com(self):
    """
    Start Com Funtion
    """
    self.AppendText("\n-----------------Start Communication to Modbus-----------------\n")

    self.stop_com_loop = False

    cmd = ("modpoll.exe -p 504 -1 192.168.1.100")

    self.AppendText("Executing Command: %s" %(cmd))

    while(not self.stop_com_loop):
        self._runcommand(cmd)

        time.sleep(1)

    self.logging_cb.Enable(True)
    self.ping_btn.Enable(True)
    self.com_btn.SetLabel(START_COM_STR)

    self.AppendText("\n-----------------End Communication to Modbus-----------------\n")

    print("Why Won't I die?")

def _com_evt(self,
             evt):
    """
    Com Button Event
    """
    if self.com_btn.GetLabelText() == START_COM_STR:
        self.logging_cb.Enable(False)
        self.ping_btn.Enable(False)
        self.com_btn.SetLabel(STOP_COM_STR)

        self.com_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.Start_Com)
        self.com_thread.daemon = True
        self.com_thread.start()

    elif self.com_btn.GetLabelText() == STOP_COM_STR:
        self.stop_com_loop = True
        # self.com_thread.join() # When this line is inserted. System Hangs
        while(True):
            print self.com_thread
            print self.com_thread.isAlive()
            if not self.com_thread.isAlive():
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        self.com_btn.SetLabel(START_COM_STR)
    else:
        self.AppendText("Unknown Start Com Button State")

def _runcommand(self,
                cmd):
    """
    Run Command given and output to text control
    """

    self.error_occured = False

    cmd_l = cmd.split(" ")

    self.pjob = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 bufsize=0,
                                 creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)

    while True:
        line = self.pjob.stdout.readline()

        skip_line = False

        for token in self.DO_NOT_PRINT_TOKEN_L:
            if ((token in line)):
                skip_line = True
        if skip_line:
            continue

        wx.Yield()

        if line.strip() == "":
            pass
        elif self.ERROR_COM_TOKEN in line:
            self.error_occured = True
            self.AppendText("%-30s~    ERROR: %s\n" %(self.GetTime(),
                                                      line.strip()))
        else:
            self.AppendText("%-30s~    %s" %(self.GetTime(),
                                             line.strip()))

        if not line: break

    # Print that error occured and when error resolves
    if self.error_occured:
        self.AppendText("\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %% ERROR OCCURED %% XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n")
        self.last_one_was_error = True
        self.AppendOverviewText("%-30s~    %% ERROR OCCURED %% "
            %(self.GetTime()))
    else:
        if self.last_one_was_error:
            self.AppendText("\n+++++++++++++++++++++ ** ERROR RESOLVED ** +++++++++++++++++++++\n")
            self.AppendOverviewText("%-30s~    ** ERROR RESOLVED ** "
                %(self.GetTime()))
        self.last_one_was_error = False

    self.pjob.wait()
    self.pjob = None
```

EDIT:
I've isolated to the line that seems to stop the thread from joining... The AppendText function seems to stop the thread from joining. I have no idea why.

Initialization of logging_ctrl

```
self.logging_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "",
                               style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
```

AppendText Method:

```
def AppendText(self,
               text):
    """
    Append text to logging text control and file is logging is enabled
    """
    self.logging_ctrl.AppendText(str(text) + '\n')
```

Comment: there's "join" in your question, but right after you set `self.stop_com_loop = True` you should actually _call_ `self.com_thread.join()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I had removed it because having the join hangs the system. I removed and used the IsAlive() method to check if it ever ended, and it doesn't. I've put it back in with a comment.

Comment: I may have an idea but you'd have to show the code for `_runcommand`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've added _runcommand

Comment: your subprocess management is bad in many ways: you shouldn't PIPE both stdout & stderr, rather redirect stderr in stdout our you may have deadlocks. And are you sure you're exiting from your `while True` loop? do you _really_ need `shell=True`. The problem is there. Remove your subprocess call you'll see the thread will exit. Do you get the "Why Won't I die?" trace? or not BTW?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the feedback. I have cleaned up _runcommand with your suggestions. Definitely looks better now. It seems it doesn't get stuck at _runcommand. When I comment out _runcommand entirely from "Start_Com" method, the join issue still is a problem.

Note that when if I do not click the stop button, this whole process can start again. It doesn't get stuck when I run it normally. I do however notice that a new thread id is created with the function call of Start_Com. "Why Won't I Die?" does not appear unfortunately...

Comment: another fishy thing: `wx.Yield()` shouldn't probably be called from a thread. `wx` definitely doesn't like threads unless you use `wxCallAfter`. Can you remove that too? now you have a thread you don't need that anyway!! (yes, I confirm it looks better now). the fact that "why don't I die" doesn't appear isn't bad news, it's just that the loop doesn't exit (which is strange since `if not line: break` should do it.

Comment: now I'm pretty sure that `wx.Yield()` from within a thread is the issue. Keep me posted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've isolated the issue to the method "AppendText". I have no idea why it would get stuck there. Specifically, right before "Why won't I die" the AppendText get's stuck. I've extended the question above with more information on this. It seems the wx.widgets is causing it to get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use most `wx` calls in threads. `wx` graphical routines must be called from main thread only.

To workaround that, there's a safe `wx.CallAfter()` method that allows to register the action from a thread.

In your `AppendText` method, just do:

```
def AppendText(self,
               text):
    """
    Append text to logging text control and file is logging is enabled
    """
    wx.CallAfter(self.logging_ctrl.AppendText,str(text) + '\n')
```

If you're in the main thread, that will do the same as before. In other threads, it will avoid the lockup you're getting because it just notes down the action to perform, and the wx mainloop processes it. You may not see the difference graphically-wise, but your thread will exit properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patients and help. This solved the issue. Is using wx.CallAfter() normal or should I not be using wx and threads like I am now?

Comment: `wx.CallAfter` is _made_ for thread situations like this. So keep on doing it. Our apps do that all the time without problem (before they were crashing)